# Custom Post Type Organisation - Taxonomies, Categories and Pages

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type `recipes` which has a number of `recipe-cut` taxonomy terms within it.

The recipes have a landing `archive` page: `/recipes`.

Each `recipe-cut` has a landing page: `/recipes/cut/bacon`.

There will also be different taxonomies such as `occasion` and `type` with the urls such as:

Occasion: `/recipes/occasion/breakfast`

Type: `/recipes/type/healthy`

Finally the single recipe pages will be:  `/recipes/recipe-slug-here`

Is this the correct way of organising custom post types, their taxonomies and sections within?

Comment: I'm unclear what you're looking for. The way you have things set up currently sounds perfectly fine, is there a different way or a modification you'd like to see with your current set up?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't necessarily a "correct" way of doing this.  This is basically what happens by default, and if this is what makes sense for your data, then this is the correct thing to do.